How to interpret top command memory usage of a process?
I wanted to understand the significance of VIRT, RES and SHR values displayed as part of top command for a process.
I have written a simple program that doesn't allocate any private memory by itself. It simply uses system functions.
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

        while(1) {
                cout<<endl<<"This is a dummy program"<<endl;
                sleep(1);
        }

        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

I have generated the execute using the following command.
g++ -o Dummy1.exe -g -Wall Dummy.cpp

Following is the top output when the above execute was run.
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND 
 4461 soumajit  20   0   13988   1772   1628 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 Dummy1.exe

What are the bare minimum shared memory segments that are contributing to the SHR value ?
Why is there a small difference between RES and SHR when I have explicitly not declared any variable ?
How is this value of VIRT allocated ?
I have captured strace output. Does it contain the sizes of the shared memory segments that contribute to the SHR value ?
brk(NULL)                               = 0x561940984000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=130951, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 130951, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f54a6877000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220\304\10\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1594864, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f54a6875000
mmap(NULL, 3702848, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f54a62e7000
mprotect(0x7f54a6460000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f54a6660000, 49152, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x179000) = 0x7f54a6660000
mmap(0x7f54a666c000, 12352, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f54a666c000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260\34\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2030544, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4131552, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f54a5ef6000
mprotect(0x7f54a60dd000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f54a62dd000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e7000) = 0x7f54a62dd000
mmap(0x7f54a62e3000, 15072, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f54a62e3000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200\272\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1700792, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3789144, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f54a5b58000
mprotect(0x7f54a5cf5000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f54a5ef4000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19c000) = 0x7f54a5ef4000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\300*\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=96616, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2192432, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f54a5940000
mprotect(0x7f54a5957000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f54a5b56000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16000) = 0x7f54a5b56000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f54a6873000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f54a6873d00) = 0
mprotect(0x7f54a62dd000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f54a5b56000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f54a5ef4000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f54a6871000
mprotect(0x7f54a6660000, 40960, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x56193f2a2000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f54a6897000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f54a6877000, 130951)          = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x561940984000
brk(0x5619409a5000)                     = 0x5619409a5000
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 3), ...}) = 0
write(1, "\n", 1)                       = 1
write(1, "This is dummy program\n", 22) = 22
nanosleep({tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=203523438}) = ? ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK (Interrupted by signal)
--- SIGINT {si_signo=SIGINT, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
+++ killed by SIGINT +++

Following is the test environment.
Linux soumajit-HP-Pavilion-Desktop-590-p0xxx 5.4.0-71-generic #79~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 25 05:45:39 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


SHR and RES are not related at all. SHR is reporting virtual memory, RES is physical memory.

https://superuser.com/questions/575202/understanding-top-command-in-unix

@Barmar my doubt is how this number 1628 is calculated and whether using strace output we can trace the value ?

I'm not sure it can be seen directly from that. Certainly none of the mmap calls with MAP_PRIVATE will be included in shared memory.

@Barmar is there any other way to establish the traceability ?

strace only shows system calls, it doesn't show operations that are done directly by the OS when loading a process into memory.

@Barmar then exactly which  are these memory segments ?  Are they related to the following shared library ?
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffa7f99000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f2090925000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2090534000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2090196000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2090eb0000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f208ff7e000)

I think you might be able to investigate this with pmap.

@Barmar I will explore pmap.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

RES is the resident physical memory the process use currently, its value may contains the SHR memory it access.
You can see this: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/does-res-in-top-reflect-any-shared-memory-803032/
